# Mod_cluster + apache + wildfly via http

Tags: apache2, wildfly, mod-cluster

I have a problem with configuring apache 2.4.10 + mod_cluster 1.3.1 + wildfly 17 - Segmentation fault in error.log in apache. When I use ajp it works fine, but not http. I tried to compile and used modules 1.3.12 version of mod_cluster but it didn't help. Anybody solved this problem? OS: debian 8

Wildfly settings:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:5.0">
    <proxy name="default" advertise-socket="modcluster" listener="default" proxies="proxy1">
        <dynamic-load-provider>
            <load-metric type="cpu"/>
        </dynamic-load-provider>
    </proxy>
</subsystem>
```

```
<server name="default-server">
    <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </host>
</server>
```

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="proxy1">
    <remote-destination host="192.168.27.4" port="7777"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

mod_cluster.conf

```
<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 192.168.27.4:7777
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster
  <VirtualHost 192.168.27.4:7777>

    <Location />
     Require ip 192.168.27
    </Location>

    KeepAliveTimeout 1800
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    ServerAdvertise on 192.168.27.4:7777
    AdvertiseFrequency 10
    #AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
    #AdvertiseGroup @ADVIP@:23364
    EnableMCPMReceive

    <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Require ip 192.168.27
    </Location>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Error:

```
[Mon Aug 26 18:43:53.683662 2019] [core:notice] [pid 29751:tid 140376589154176] AH00052: child pid 29756 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

When I try to enter to my page I see blank page and errors like: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Comment: Hello Margulan, it is very difficult to guess without any logs or the core itself. The httpd we are running m_c 1.3.11.Final with the most these days is 2.4.29. It should work with 2.4.10 too though. Could you share the logs? You can edit any sensitive info like addresses or hostnames out.

Comment: @MichalKarmBabacek Did you try to use http between wildfly and mod_cluster with apache? My OS is debian 8, so the latest version of apache is 2.4.10. I need http because I use websockets.